# HtmlAgilityPack cannot find node

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am trying to get `Start` called span from [Here](http://www.mobafire.com/league-of-legends/build/7-11-korean-mf-build-destroy-the-carry-added-support-468469)

Chrome gives me this xPath: `//*[@id="guide-pages"]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/h2`

But HtmlAgilityPack returns null, after I tried remove them one by one; this works: `//*[@id="guide-pages"]/div[2]/div[1]` , but not the rest of them.

My full Code:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
var text = await ReadUrl();
doc.LoadHtml(text);
Console.WriteLine($"Getting Data From: {doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//head/title").InnerText}"); //Works fine
Console.WriteLine(doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='guide-pages']/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/h2") == null);
```

Output:

```
Getting Data From: Miss Fortune Build Guide : [7.11] KOREAN MF Build - Destroy the Carry! [Added Support] :: League of Legends Strategy Builds
True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use xpath from Chrome. Use LINQ in HtmlAgilityPack instead. For example
`.Descendants("div")` will give you all the `div` under 1 html node. Each html node will have meta data like id, attributes(classes...), and you can query your wanted div from there.
This is one handy method to check if a `HtmlNode` has classes or not.

```
    public static bool HasClass(this HtmlNode node, params string[] classValueArray)
    {
        var classValue = node.GetAttributeValue("class", "");
        var classValues = classValue.Split(' ');
        return classValueArray.All(c => classValues.Contains(c));
    }
```

Comment: So how will I get the data? I didn't get it.

Comment: do you know where is your expected `div`? does it have any classnames or id?

Comment: it's parent has a class called `item-title`. I'll try it.

Comment: `#guide-pages > div.col-left > div.guide-head.self-clear.mb10 > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > div.build-wrap > div > div.self-clear.mb10 > div.self-clear > div:nth-child(3) > div > div:nth-child(1) > a > div.item-title > span` is the span's selector btw.

Comment: So, I did them like you suggested, but couldn't get the span; so i get the xPath of it; and this xPath works: `/html[1]/body[1]/div[9]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[6]/div[1]/div[2]/a[1]/div[2]/span`

Comment: `doc.DocunentNode.Descendants("div").FirstOrDefault(d => d.HasClass("item-title")?.ChildNodes` this line will give you every childnodes under `item-title div`